# Python assertEqal string - ignore part of it

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm using python 3.6.7

In tests, I'm using assertEqual to compare string objets. Those strings contain some time data. since this data is different from test to test, I want to ignore this data. Is it doable?

for example, this is the comparable object:

```
obj1 = '{"field1": "field1", "field2": "field2", "created_at": "2019-06-16T07:12:46.429536Z", "field2": "field3"}'
```

I want to do something like:

```
obj1 = '{"field1": "field1", "field2": "field2", "created_at": ANY, "field2": "field3"}'
obj2 = '{"field1": "field1", "field2": "field2", "created_at": "2019-06-16T07:12:46.429536Z", "field2": "field3"}'
assertEqual(obj1, obj2)
```

Comment: Those strings look like serialised json to me, I'd rather compare values of the individual fields rather than the overall representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the strings are serialized json objects, I'd rather compare the data than the representation which may vary and break the tests randomly. For example:

```
import json
v1 = json.loads(obj1)
v2 = json.loads(obj2)

del v1['created_at']
del v2['created_at']
assertEqual(v1, v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete this part from the string using regex before comparing

```
import re
obj1 = '{"field1": "field1", "field2": "field2", "created_at": ANY, "field2": "field3"}'
obj2 = '{"field1": "field1", "field2": "field2", "created_at": "2019-06-16T07:12:46.429536Z", "field2": "field3"}'

obj1 = re.sub(r' "created_at[^,]*,', '', obj1)
obj2 = re.sub(r' "created_at[^,]*,', '', obj2)
assertEqual(obj1, obj2)
```

Comment: I don't think your RE is entirely correct. Just try moving the "created_at" field to the front (e.g. `obj2 = '{"field1": "field1", "created_at": "2019-06-16T07:12:46.429536Z", "field2": "field2", "field2": "field3"}'`) and see what happens...

Comment: @ImperishableNight, well yes, the regex was in the situation that the text is like this, but you are right, ```"created_at[^,]*,``` will work in both cases